# Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. Error in Cosmos Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, operating-system, c#-2.0, cosmos

I am trying to work on Operating System in C# through Cosmos. I am using Visual Studio 2022.
The problem is every time I press create project button after selecting the COSMOS Kernal project template I get the following error

**Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown**

[image: image of error]

Please help,

regards

I am trying to create COSMOS Project in Visual Studio 2022 using Cosmos Kernal template and keep getting **System.Exception** error.